# Как открыть картинку через Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, img

Мой код:

```
import os
os.system("D\picture.jpg")
```

в консоли работает, а в PyCharm нет... Что делать?

Comment: Все, я нашла свою ошибку. просто эта картинка уже была занята другим приложением, вот и не открывалась. всем большое спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 7):

Открыть наверное значит загрузить для показа (или обработки)? Если да то попробуйте через PIL, примерно так:

```
from PIL import Image
#...
img = Image.open(r'D:\picture.jpg')
img.show()
```

Comment: Похоже, что человек хочет открыть ее в приложении по умолчанию, и при запуске из PyCharm что-то не так с окружением.

Comment: если использовать PIL, то картинка должна быть в папке с проектом?

Comment: Она может быть где угодно.

Comment: если обратный слэш есть в пути, то лучше `r''` константу использовать (в данном случае это не важно, так как `'\p' == r'\p'`, но в общем случае `'\t' != r'\t'`).

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы открыть картинку, используя приложение по умолчанию, на Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

os.startfile(r'D:\picture.jpg')
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так (картинка откроется в веб-браузере):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(r"D:\picture.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете это сделать, например, с помощью специализированных библиотек для обработки изображений и обработки данных. [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) требует установки дополнительных пакетов. Но, при этом, позволяет, помимо прочего, широкий спектр возможностей для обработки изображений. Вторая [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) устанавливается легко, интегрируется в pyCharm и позволяет использовать довольно удобный встроенный интерфейс для просмотра. К сожалению, эта библиотека не предоставляет возможности для обработки изображений, а только для их визуализации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Opencv**

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('x.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**matplotlib**:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = plt.imread('x.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

**matplotlib**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**opencv**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установка **opencv**:

```
sudo apt-get install -y cmake make libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
mkdir ./opencv/build
cd ./opencv/build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make -j4 
make install
```

Флаг j указывает число процессов, которые будут использованы при установке

Установка **matplotlib**:

```
pip install matplotlib
pip install pillow
```

Если библиотека pillow не будет установлена, то можно будет пользоваться только * *.png*